# estar + gerundio vs imperfecto

Tags: gramática, pretérito-imperfecto

What're the differences between those both constructions?
If yesterday I had lost my dog and was looking him should I say

> Ayer estaba buscando mi perro.

or

> Ayer buscaba mi perro.

And generally, when should I use estar + gerundio, and when past tenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would be translated to the same sentence in English

> I was looking for my dog yesterday

but, in order to explain what `estar` is doing to the sentence, ... you have to remove the **status** of **looking for**

> Yo buscaba a mi perro ayer.
>
> I looked for my dog yesterday

*there is still a continuity*

VS

> Yo estaba buscando a mi perro ayer
>
> I was looking for my dog yesterday

Both `estaba buscando` and `buscaba` are in the imperfect tense, meaning there is no termination of the event.

---

Estar means to be in a current, specific, and particular state of time or place.  So to say

> Estaba buscando a ....

means, `I was in a state of searching`.. not `I searched`..

> Yo estaba buscando a mi perro todo el día de ayer.
>
> I was in a state of searching for my dog all day yesterday

VS

> Yo buscaba a mi perro todo el día de ayer.
>
> I searched for my dog all day yesterday.

Comment: Wait, imperfecto is equivalent of english past continous, and indefinido is equivalent of past simple, so 'lo busce' doesn't mean 'I looked him', and 'lo buscaba' 'I was looking him'?

Comment: yes, that's right... though I wouldn't call it indefinido .

Comment: pretérito is the "past simple" you're referring to.

Comment: So did you correctly translated 'Yo buscaba a mi perro' as 'I looked for my dog'? Doesn't is mean 'I was looking for my dog'?

Comment: I only translated it that way, literally, to show you what estar is doing to the sentence.  They still both translate to the same thing.

Comment: So 'Ayer estaba buscando' means I am still looking for the dog (today)?

Comment: No, it just means that you never stopped looking, it doesn't necessarily mean that you are still looking today.  That would be another sentence altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Yo buscaba a mi perro. Le no se usa ya que le es pronombre de objeto indirecto y el perro seria objeto directo. Le como pronombre de objeto directo solamente se usa cuando hablamos de personas, para lo demás se usan los pronombres de objeto directo.

buscaba a mi perro  /   lo buscaba
 estoy buscando a mi perro  /  lo estoy buscando

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. No veo como responde esto a la pregunta.

Comment: @BrianH. además, *le* se usa con personas o cosas humanizadas, tal como sería un perro (o por lo menos, *yo* le trato a mi perro casi como si lo fuese jajaja).

Comment: @BrianH. esta respuesta es un comentario a una edición que el usuario ha realizado sobre otra respuesta, y por tanto debería ser convertido a comentario en la respuesta editada. Se recomienda al nuevo usuario consultar las secciones [tour] y [answer] para saber más sobre el sitio.